# how to keep element in screen when scrolling in css?

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-position

I have a website with a very big header that will go out of screen when scrolling (I want this), then I have two columns. I'd like the left column (it's a section at the moment) to remain visible all the time while the right one scrolls down.

position: fixed; is not what I'm looking for, as I would like the left column to scroll until it reaches the top of the screen, and then stay there.

I know this can be done with javascript, but is it possible to do this just using css?

Comment: `position: sticky` will solve the problem as soon as it will be implemented everywhere. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: and for polyfill see here http://www.sitepoint.com/css-position-sticky-introduction-polyfills/ ;)  codepen demo http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/piFxy